# Stop rsync scheduled task race condition (large directory, small time interval)

Tags: rsync, backup, multithreading

Platform information:

`OpenBSD 6.2 amd64`

`$ rsync --version
rsync version 3.1.2  protocol version 31`

I'm trying to sync a large directory (4TB) using the following `daily.local` file (for Linux admins, this is essentially a cron daily task):

```
#!/bin/sh
# Sync the primary storage device to the backup disk
/usr/local/bin/rsync -avz /mnt/media_primary/ /mnt/media_backup/
```

The initial rsync copy takes more than a day.
After a day or two, I end up with multiple running copies of rsync in my processes list: new ones are started as scheduled and these new processes seem to be competing with each other and not finishing the task (quickly at least)!

Is there a way to make a new rsync process aware of other rsync processes (or another way to avoid rsync race conditions)?

I know I could just run rsync manually to copy over the directory the first time and/or increase the scheduled time interval. This question is more for my interest as I was unable to find information on the net about this topic.

Comment: One popular way to prevent programs started from cron from stomping on each other is to use the [flock](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=flock) command. Does OpenBSD have that?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! A port for the command line version is available via pkg_add. The flock() system call is available in the default install using the <fcntl.h> header.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/82857/prevent-duplicate-cron-jobs-running/82863#82863

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way round this problem (if the backup directory is on it's own partition) is to leave the volume unmounted, mounting just before starting the rsync command. This negates the need to use `flock` and may have the benefit of prolonging drive longevity/reducing power consumption.

`/etc/fstab`: add the `noauto` option to the partition so it doesn't get automatically mounted on boot

In the `daily.local` or `cron.daily` scheduled task:

```
#!/bin/sh
mount /mnt/media_backup && \
/usr/local/bin/rsync -avz /mnt/media_primary/ /mnt/media_backup/ && \
umount /mnt/media_backup
```

The double ampersand operator (`&&`) will only start the next command if the previous command is successful. Hence, if the backup disk can't be mounted (because it is already mounted and rsync is already running on the partition), the rest of the command will not proceed.

Answer (score 3):

A solution that would be somewhat similar to [Mark's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/466016/116858), but without requiring changes to the `/etc/fstab` or mounting and unmounting filesystems:

```
#!/bin/sh

lockdir=/tmp/file-copy.lock

if ! mkdir "$lockdir"; then
   echo 'File copy already in progress' >&2
   exit 1
fi

trap 'rmdir "$lockdir"' EXIT

PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin

rsync -ai ...
```

A few notes about this:

1. The `mkdir` is an atomic operation, much like `mount`, that will fail if the directory already exists, but create the directory if it doesn't. This is safer than first checking for a lock *file* and then creating it (two steps with a possibility of a race condition in-between).
2. The `EXIT` trap ensures that the lock directory is deleted when the script terminates.  The lock directory would also be deleted on reboots (by the system) since it's in `/tmp`.
3. I set `PATH` to the appropriate value rather than calling `rsync` with its full path. This is purely a cosmetic thing, but could be useful if the script later is expanded to use other commands from the OpenBSD ports collection (such as `restic` or `borgbackup`).
4. The `-z` option to `rsync` is really only needed over *very slow* network connections (when compressing/decompressing data is done quicker than the network bandwidth), and *never* for local copying. I also tend to favour the `-i` (`--itemize-changes`) over `-v` (`--verbose`), as this will tell me exactly why a file was transferred.

For backing up large amounts of data safely, I would generally recommend using a purpose written backup software over `rsync`, such as [`restic`](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/ports/sysutils/restic/) or [`borgbackup`](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/ports/sysutils/borgbackup/). These two additionally do data deduplication and encryption, and `borgbackup` may optionally do compression. `restic` is good in the sense that it allows one to save backups to an external server (over e.g. `sftp`), even if that server does not have `restic` installed, whereas `borgbackup` requires that the software is installed on the target system.  Both `restic` and `borgbackup` handles backup repository locking.